# Cant get value for a single textbox field in form - others fine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

This is really annoying me now at this stage :(

i have a standard search form with a text input and a series of html dropdowns, i try to pass these values off as parameters in the url for a search function but can only get the dropdown values and not the textbox.

The code is as follows

```
<div class="span4">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label for="focusedInput" class="control-label">Location</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="userInp" CssClass="input-xlarge" placeholder="Where do you want to live?" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span2">                           
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label for="focusedInput" class="control-label">Uni Distance:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select id="uniDist" runat="server" class="input-medium focused">
                                            <option value="0.25">Within 1/4 mile</option>
                                            <option value="0.5">Within 1/2 mile</option>
                                            <option value="1">Within 1 mile</option>
                                            <option value="3">Within 3 miles</option>
                                            <option value="5">Within 5 miles</option>
                                            <option value="10">Within 10 miles</option>
                                            <option value="15">Within 15 miles</option>
                                            <option value="20">Within 20 miles</option>
                                            <option value="30">Within 30 miles</option>
                                            <option value="40">Within 40 miles</option>
                                        </select>               
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span2 ">    
                                <label for="focusedInput" class="control-label">Property type:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <select id="houseType" runat="server" class="input-medium focused">
                                        <option value="Any">Any</option>
                                        <option value="3">Terraced</option>
                                        <option value="2">Semi Detached</option>
                                        <option value="1">Detached</option>
                                        <option value="4">Apartment</option>
                                        <option value="5">Bedsit</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>  
                        <div class="row">                         
                            <div class="span4">                           
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label for="focusedInput" class="control-label">Min bedrooms:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select id="bedNo" runat="server" class="input-medium focused">
                                            <option value="Any">Any</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5+</option>
                                        </select>               
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>                          
                        <div class="row">                         
                            <div class="span2">                           
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label for="focusedInput" class="control-label">Minimum Price</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select id="minPrice" runat="server" class="input-medium focused">
                                            <option selected="selected" value="Any">No min</option>
                                            <option value="50">£50 per week</option>
                                            <option value="100">£100 per week</option>
                                            <option value="125">£125 per week</option>
                                            <option value="150">£150+ per week</option>
                                        </select>               
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span2"> 
                                <label for="focusedInput" class="control-label">Maximum Price</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <select id="maxPrice" runat="server" class="input-medium focused">
                                            <option selected="selected" value="Any">No max</option>
                                            <option value="50">£50 per week</option>
                                            <option value="100">£100 per week</option>
                                            <option value="125">£125 per week</option>
                                            <option value="150">£150+ per week</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>      

                        </div>  

                    </div>
```

server side based on button click

```
protected void getSearchResults(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = String.Format("searchResults.aspx?userInput={0}&Distance={1}&propType={2}&noBeds={3}&minPrice={4}&maxPrice={5}",userInp.Text,uniDist.Value,houseType.Value,bedNo.Value,minPrice.Value,maxPrice.Value);
            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
```

in this version ive tried using an asp TextBox instead of a HTML input running at server but still the text value comes back as "". Can anyone shed some light here, its just gone after midnight and im beginning to go crazy at something so dumb ;)

Comment: How are you submitting the form ? Can you post your server-side code as well please ?

Comment: editted to show how im processing the data

Comment: Ok so the late night lack of sleep has got to me, i've sussed it out and its a pretty basic one :/ i have my main form with runat server but also a secondary form tag, which this code was nested within - this is why the values werent coming through. I'll post an answer to this effect when SO lets me :) sorry tho and thanks for the input anyways guys - im off to bed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i had essentially the following

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">

<form>
<fieldset>

//form data here
</fieldset>
</form>

</form>
```

So basically having a form within a form meant that i could not get the values on Postback, hope this helps someone!

Comment: Ah yeah.. that old chestnut. One form per page with webforms !

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're not URL encoding your form values. Try using Server.URLEncode: -

```
string url = String.Format("searchResults.aspx?userInput={0}&Distance={1}&propType={2}&noBeds={3}&minPrice={4}&maxPrice={5}", Server.UrlEncode(userInp.Text), Server.UrlEncode(uniDist.Value) .. etc
```

(You'll need to use URLDecode the other side)

I've tried your solution and when I submit the form, I am definitely getting values in all the form controls including the textboxes, but if I enter something like 'the moon' for "where do you want to live?", it's not escaped properly and is not a valid URL.

Comment: this is a fair point actually so a point for the URL encode - i overlooked this one!